# Prepairing a Sodium Acetate buffer - Meaning of molarity

Tags: acid-base, ph, titration, buffer

We have instructions to prepare a "50 mM Sodium Acetate, pH 5 solution". I am not entirely sure what does the molarity refer to in this case. Does it mean:

- Add Sodium Acetate salt up to 50 mM, and adjust with Acetic Acid until pH 5 - Na+ remains at 50 mM, Acetate- higher
- Add Acetic Acid up to 50 mM, and adjust with Acetic Acid until pH 5 - Na+ remains at 50 mM, Acetate- higher
- Add Sodium Acetate salt up to X mM, and add Y mM Acetic Acid, so that X + Y = 50 mM Acetate ions - Acetate- ends up at 50 mM, Na+ lower

Answer (score 2):

It is the molarity of total acetic acid/acetate content, so the 3rd option.

It is quite general principle applied in the pH buffer context. You can have a wide rage of $\ce{pH}$ values with the particular buffer type, with the same total molarity of "active substance", like citrate, phosphate or mixed buffers, being adjusted by variable amount of strong acid/base.

Note that calculation of $\ce{pH}$ from concentrations is not exact, because it is just approximation of activities. The key is, you have to know in advance the ratio, e.g. from the handy $\mathrm{pH}$ buffer lab tables or other sources. The alternative is starting with pure acetic acid, or better from the approximately precalculated ratio, and adjusting final $\mathrm{pH}$ by $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{HCl}$.

Sometimes, preparation of buffers is combined with the constant target ionic strength by addition of indifferent salt. In our case, it would be the less of added salt ( like e.g. NaCl ) for higher acetate content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the goal ion is always the one that has a dissociation constant, right? e.g. in a 50 mM Tris/HCl, the goal compond for the 50 mM is the Tri

Comment: Rather conjugate(d) acid/base system, like HA <=> H+ + A-, or B + H+ <=> BH+, where A,,B may or may not be neutral.